# Testflight linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have just started working on objective C and I have very basic knowledge of it. I am migrating from other programming language.

My former developer emailed me the whole code folder and when I tried to run it build process is failed with a strange message: 
"ld: library not found for -lTestFlight
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I am using xcode 5.0.2

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278538/no-changes-in-testflight-libraries-and-xcode-5-now-says-ld-library-not-found-f

Comment: Your text Flight is not wired properly, Question is, if you would like to re wire it, or un wire it?